# How to structure syntax for `SELECT` with `IN` SQL Server Query from Node via `mssql` package

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to make use of `SELECT` and `IN` to match on values between tables from two different SQL databases in my Node app that makes use of the `mssql` package:

My question is, if I am passing a variable representing that array of values in my Node app, that looks like this:

```
const arr = ["1323", "2311", "1234"];
```

would I do this?:

```
 N'[arr]'
```

or this?

```
N'arr'
```

Or is there some other syntax I should use?

Right now, this is the full query I'm passing:

```
// An array *like* this, saved in a variable name:
const sourceIdArr = ["1323", "2311", "1234"];

const selectInQuery = `
  DECLARE @sourceIdArr NVARCHAR(4000) = N 'sourceIdArr'
  SELECT NDID FROM SR_Empsheets
  WHERE NDID IN ( SELECT value from openjson(@sourceIdArr) )
`;
```

Will this work, or should I approach it differently?

Comment: mssql supports parameters.  See: https://github.com/tediousjs/node-mssql#input-name-type-value

Comment: Can you help me understand what that would look like in the above scenario? How would I pass the parameter here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So something like

```
const sourceIdArr = ["1323", "2311", "1234"];

const selectInQuery = `
  SELECT NDID FROM SR_Empsheets
  WHERE NDID IN ( SELECT value from openjson(@sourceIdArr) )
`;

new sql.Request()
       .input("sourceIdArr", sql.VarChar(sql.MAX), JSON.stringify(sourceIdArr) ) 
       .execute(selectInQuery , (err, result) => {
           // ... error checks

           console.dir(result)
       });
```